# Neo4j parallel runtime and GPU

Tags: neo4j, parallel-processing, gpu, neo4j-parallel-runtime

Looks like Neo4j is naturally stepping into the world of parallel processing with the brand new parallel runtime in version 5.13.0.

Thus, I have a question: Is it possible with Neo4j to utilize GPU power for parallel processing instead of the CPU? If not, do you have plans to support it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Parallel Runtime is a very powerful mechanism for certain queries to parallelise the processing of a single query (though parallel processing isn't new when you have multiple parallel queries).

However, GPU's are not supported by the parallel runtime and it is not really foreseen either.